# How to use output from one 'do shell script' for another one in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm using a Mail.app rule (MacOS Mojave) that creates a TaskWarrior task for the selected email message by using AppleScript that uses a 'do shell script' command.

Creating the task is no problem, but I want to annotate the task, which requires that you use the output from the shell script - which is "Created task [number]". Because annotating the task is the following shell script: task [number] annotate [your annotation, in my case a link to the email message].

I thought I managed to get the "Created task [number]" result from the first shell script to "task [number]" which is the beginning of the second shell script, but the Result is now that No command is specified - assuming 'information'.

I've tried to use delay 1, so that one shell script wait for the other to finish, but to no avail.

This is the specific script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of selectedMessages
    set messageid to message id of theMessage
    -- Make URL (must use URL-encoded values for "<" and ">")
    set urlText to "message://" & "%3c" & messageid & "%3e"
    set onderwerp to subject of theMessage
    set DueDate to display dialog "Wat is de due date?" default answer "friday"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/task add Email over " & onderwerp & " beantwoorden due:" & (text returned of DueDate) & " project:Work +email"
    -- This all works as it should. A task is created with the email subject and a due date that I give it. However, from here something goes wrong
    set task to the result
    set laatste to rich text 1 thru -2 of task
    set annotate to rich text 9 thru -1 of laatste
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/" & annotate & " annotate" & urlText
end tell
```

I expected that the output would be that task [number] is annotated with urlText of the message. But I get:

> error "Mail got an error: No command specified - assuming
>   'information'. No matches." number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No command specified - assuming 'information'.

Ask yourself why TaskWarrior cannot see that the command is “annotate”.  It’s because your second command syntax is wrong. Change

```
& " annotate" &
```

To

```
& " annotate " &
```

Note the space.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was it. So sorry for the basic mistake!